# What is the best way to use startSwipe function of ItemTouchHelper

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I created a custom `LayoutManager` and `TouchHelper.Callback` to have a tinder-like card stack. I want my layout manager to allow only the first item to have a touch event. Firstly I override the `isItemViewSwipeEnabled()` of `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` to disable touch event for each child. As the last step, I need to allow the first item to have a touch event only. However, I am failed to do so. Is anybody know how to overcome it?

- StackLayoutManager to create child views.
- StackTouchHelperCallback to disallow default touch events.
- StackView a custom RecyclerView.

This is the custom view hierarchy I developed. If anybody developed some kind of views, can them help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can `override` the `getMovementFlags` `method` and `return` 0 in case you dont want to allow any movement, otherwise `return` appropriate direction `flags`.

```
override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder:RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
        return if(viewHolder.adapterPosition == 0) /* return appropriate direction flags */ else 0
}
```

Comment: Hi @mightyWOZ thanks! I don't have any problems with directions. It is the touch event issue. I disallow the touch event for all children by `isItemViewSwipeEnabled()`. Now I just need to allow a touch event for only the first child. Do you know this is possible and if so how?